# Why does template ordering matter when defining a method?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have the following code:

```
template<int n> 
struct array_container{double arr[n];};

template<int n>
struct avg{
    double first[n], second[n];

   template <int q>
   array_container<q> get_avg(double p) const;
};
```

I can add a definition for `get_avg` like this:

```
template<int n>
template<int q>
array_container<q>  avg<n>::get_avg(double p) const{
    array_container<q>   result;
    const int m = min(n,q);
    for(int k=0;k<m;k++){result.arr[k] = p*first[k] + (1-p) * second[k];}
    return result;
}
```

If I were to replace the first two lines of the definition, namely:

```
template<int n>
template<int q>
```

with any one of these:

```
template<int q>
template<int n>
```

```
template<int n, int q>
```

```
template<int q, int n>
```

compilation would fail . Why is this so? I see no significance in the order of the templates when defining for `array_container<q> avg<n>::get_avg(double p) const` .

Edit:
I understand that in the current standard the ordering of the template parameter clauses in the definition must correspond exactly to that of the declaration. My question is relating to the design of the language.

Is there any reason, relating to logic or consistency, why my alternative examples could not be considered equally as valid? Especially since the compiler can already deduce the correct candidate if I provide it with an "incorrect" ordering.

Comment: Because grammar follows **rules**... Why you write `int *&` for a reference to a pointer and not `int &*`... As C++ does not allows pointer to reference one could say that the compiler could just guess (as in you example). However by doing that, you **make the grammar more complicated** (and C++ grammar is already very complex). Programming language is not like spoken language where rule are somewhat more flexible (but a language like English was not designed for the purpose of making grammar checker software easy...)

Comment: Logic also follows rigid rules. If you interpret template parameter clauses as universal quantifiers (as in "template<int n> ...." means  "forall int n" ) then you could easily see how my examples would be considered equivalent. They specify a definition going over all possible "int n" and all possible "int q". Ie.  
**∀ n∈ int , ∀ q ∈ int, define array_container<q>  avg<n>::get_avg(double p) const as ...**

The order or way of grouping universal quantifiers over the same domain is irrelevant.  **∀ q, ∀ n** is the same as **∀ n ∀ q**, is the same as **∀ n, q,**.

Comment: The question would then be: does the language or templates have any additional features that would make a language extension treating them as universal quantifiers (thus allowing my examples to compile) problematic. I know this somewhat exceeds perceived scope of the original question, but this is what I really wanted to know.

Comment: The question could then be: Would making the definition more general have any benefit (other than having multiple ways of doing the same thing)? In general, a feature should be useful to be added to the language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this so?

Because when providing an **out-of-class definition** the first parameter clause `template<int n>` corresponds to the outermost enclosing class template while the second parameter clause `template<int q>` corresponds to the member template `get_avg` itself. More importanty when providing an out-of-class definition for the member template, the outermost parameter clause(for the class template(if any)) must come first, then the clause for the member templates(if any) .

```
template<int n>  //parameter clause corresponding to the outermost class template
template<int q>  //parameter claluse corresponding to the the member template itself
array_container<q>  avg<n>::get_avg(double p) const{
    array_container<q>   result;
    const int m = min(n,q);
    for(int k=0;k<m;k++){result.arr[k] = p*first[k] + (1-p) * second[k];}
    return result;
}
```